# Как скопировать текст в <span> игнорируя вложенные <span> элементы? beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, lxml

На странице есть динамическая таблица, которая обновляется раз в 30 секунд. С помощью beautifulsoup4 и lxml нахожу нужную ячейку и копирую ее текст  `current_l[item] = current_d[8].find("span").find("span").text`. Но редко (7/3400) в скопированном тексте находится вложенный span `Лак для волос <span class="Jcodx">500мл</span> schwarzkopf`. Как избавиться от этого?

Answer (score 0):

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
question = '<span>Лак для волос <span class="Jcodx">500мл</span> schwarzkopf</span>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(question)
span = soup.find("span")
for el in span.find_all('span'):
    el.decompose()
span.text.replace('  ',' ')
```

###### Вывод:

```console
'Лак для волос schwarzkopf'
```

`.decompose()` удаляет элемент из дерева. Т.е. мы проходимся по детям элемента, ищем вложенные `<span>` и убираем их. После того как убрали, могут лишние двойные пробелы остаться.

После удаления можно забирать текст без вложенных тегов

Возможно есть более элегантное решение, но это рабочим должно быть под Вашу задачу.